# syntax error on #pragma kernal Main

Tags: unity-game-engine, syntax-error, shader, compute-shader

I have the following shader:

```
#pragma kernal Main

RWTexture@D<float4>Reult;
[numthreads(8,8,1)]

void Main (uint3 id:SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    Result[id,xy]=float4(id.x & id.y, (id.x & 15)/15.0, (id.y & 15)/15.0, 0.0);
}
```

in unity.
However this creates the error "Shader error in ":Parse error: syntax error at line 1" //that is     `#pragma kernal Main`

I have looked around but #pragma kernal [name of main function] seems like the correct syntax what am I doing wrong?

This is in unity 5.0.1 32 bits edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"kern**e**l", not "kern**a**l".

[See: Unity Compute Shaders](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ComputeShaders.html)

RWTexture@D -> RWTexture2D will be your next compile error.
Followed by "Reult" -> "Result", and then "id,xy" -> "id.xy".